# Linker Error when using the SDL Library: _main already defined in main.obj

Tags: c++, c, sdl, linker-errors, program-entry-point

So I already know why this error happens, inside the SDL_main.h file a 'main' macro is being created, which will cause problems with your actual main function.

It's just that none of the obvious workarounds seem to be helping me. I have tried:

1. Defining my main function with (int argc, char* argv[]).
2. Tried it with C linkage like the comments in SDL_main.h suggest:

   ```
   *  The application's main() function must be called with C linkage,
   *  and should be declared like this:
   *  \code
   *  #ifdef __cplusplus
   *  extern "C"
   *  #endif
   *  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   *  {
   *  }
   *  \endcode
   ```
3. Tried undefining main.

Are there any other tricks I can try in order to get the main function working normally again?

Comment: Undefining main works but you have to undef after sdl inclusion and before your main procedure definition. Can you show us the code?

Comment: Done, not sure how much help it really is.

Comment: I did the undef in that exact order but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also this at the top of your `main.cpp` file:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
```

That is supposed to cause SDL to skip all of its `main` nonsense.

Note that it needs to happen before you include `SDL`:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
```

Comment: My "main" goes white again (no longer a macro) but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It's probably something wrong with your build system then. If you can't figure it out, try compiling a very simple program, possibly even without an IDE, and slowly move it closer to your current configuration until you find what's causing the issue. It's very unlikely that someone online can magically guess what's wrong with your project file.

Comment: Yeah, turns out that my messy file structure was the problem. Lesson learned I guess.