# Getting screen resolution in C, w/o "windows.h"

Tags: c, sdl-2, mingw-w64

Just working on a small project using SDL2...

**System info**: Windows

**App info**: using C (pure C, no c++), mingw-x64 & SDL2.

Now;

Firstly, `SDL.h` requires the `main` function to be renamed as `WinMain`.

On the other hand, when getting the screen resolution, I tended to use the `GetSystemMetrics` function, which requires `windows.h` to be included in the pre-processor section and at this point, `WinMain` in my code conflicts with `WinMain` declared previously in `winbase.h`. When I'm using both (`SDL.h` and `windows.h`), compiler responds:

> previous declaration of 'WinMain' was here: `int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);`

That's because, `WinMain` is declared somewhere in the `winbase.h`, which is auto-included via `windows.h`.

Is there a way to get the screen resolution w/o using `GetSystemMetrics` / `windows.h`? Any other ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594714/how-can-i-get-the-screen-resolution-using-sdl2

Comment: *SDL.h requires the main function to be renamed as WinMain* Thats not true. If you have `main()` or `WinMain()` as entry point of your program is determined by what windows subsystem you write code for (CONSOLE or WINDOWS (or others that are irrelevant here)). Also, simply renaming `main()`  to `WinMain()` won't work as both take different parameters. The error message you got tells you that. What does your definition of `WinMain()` look like?

Comment: There is just no requirement at all that #include windows.h also requires WinMain().  Using the winapi works just fine in a console app that starts from main() for example, including GetSystemMetrics().  Hard to guess how this train jumped off the rails.  But you certainly need to delete your WinMain() function, SDL already takes care of that.

Comment: @Swordfish : When using `main`, compiler complains about `WinMain` not to be found. Can't remember the exact address, but somewhere on the web I came across a get around by replacing the `main` as `WinMain`. Gave it a try... and this solved my problem --though no sure about the internals.

Anyway, `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode` seems to solve my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Internals: [How SDL2 does its initialisation magic on Windows](https://djrollins.com/2016/10/02/sdl-on-windows/) and how to get rid of that behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803842/3975177

Comment: `previous declaration of 'WinMain' was here` most likely means that you have declared/defined `WinMain` with different return type or parameter set, and C don't have function overloading, so that is a conflict. Modify your function definition to match API requirements. And no, SDL certainly don't require WinMain, but you already have links about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I've realized what I was doing wrong...

For the linking phase, I was using the following libraries and the linker was complaining about the `WinMain` function not to be found.

```
-lSDL2main
-lSDL2
```

Then I added the mingw32 library as shown below and the problem got solved (the order of the libraries does matter I think).

```
-lmingw32
-lSDL2main
-lSDL2
```